# Selenium Allure NoSuchMethodError

Tags: selenium, allure

I tried to run the Selenium Allure but got error which is

> NoSuchMethodError:
>   ru.yandex.qatools.allure.config.AllureConfig.areTestNgParametersEnabled()

My project hosted on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/peterwkc/selenium_allure)

Please help me on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: show the exact piece of code that is causing this error... don't just point to a repo and expect people to go through the entire thing guessing what might have triggered this.

Comment: It looks allure version is causing the problem. Can you change the allure version as 1.4.23 or 1.4.24.RC2

Comment: How to change the allure version to 1.4.23? Which jar to change?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by change allure-testng-adpator to 1.4.23